# python script to read items from the file into json objects

Tags: python, json, for-loop, curl, patch

I have a file with IPs. I need to go over each entry and write them into json objects. My JSON objects takes "ip": "x.x.x.x", "subnet": "y" and action as parameters. The IP and subnet values are written in the file. Finally I am using curl to PATCH these JSON objects using an API call. Any thoughts on how I can achieve this?

Sample Input file is :

1.1.1.1/24
2.2.2.2/16 and so on

I got this far ..

```
import os
import requests
import urllib3

# check if size of file is 0
if os.stat("ip.txt").st_size == 0:
    print('File is empty')
else:
    print('File is not empty')

url = 'https://api.server.com/service/6sxyz/acl/5xUrx/entries'
payload = open("request.json")
head = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'X-Key': 'xxxx'}

with open('ip.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
           if(len(word)>2):
                ip=word

           else:
                subnet=word
                print(subnet)

        data = {'op': 'create', 'ip': ip,'subnet': subnet}
        r = requests.patch(url, data, headers=head)
```

I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ip_curl.py", line 13, in <module>
    payload = open("request.json")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'request.json'
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: Could you provide an input and desired output file?

Comment: _Any thoughts on how I can achieve this?_ Yes, try doing it yourself, and come back if you encounter a **specific technical issue**. Until then, this is far too broad/vague.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Really helpful.

Comment: @codingyo It's difficult to do more when there is so little to work with.

Comment: Delete the line giving you the error and try again. Nothing else in your code relies on it :-D

Comment: What is `request.json` for? You're not using it at all. The problem is the file doesn't exist, and `open('request.json')` is trying to open the file for reading, not writing, so there's an error because the file isn't there. If you want to write something to the file, you have to use `open('request.json', mode='w')`. But, as the previous commenter pointed out, you're not using the file for anything at all, so you might as well ditch it.

Comment: Yup.. That fixed it. It was the remains of another code :P

Answer (score 0):

I am free of errors now. But the PATCH call is not resulting in the required result.

```
import os
import requests
import urllib3
import json

# check if size of file is 0
if os.stat("ip.txt").st_size == 0:
    print('File is empty')
else:
    print('File is not empty')

url = 'https://api.server.com/service/6sxyz/acl/5xUrx/entries''

head = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'X-Key': 'xxxx'}

with open('ip.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        ip = ""
        subnet = ""
        for word in line.split():
           if(len(word)>2):
                ip=word

           else:
                subnet=word
                print(subnet)

        data = {'op': 'create', 'ip': ip,'subnet': subnet}
        print data
        r = requests.patch(url, data, headers=head)
```

This is the required curl which works independent of the script or file input -

```
curl -H "X-Key: " -H "Content-type: application/json" -X PATCH https://api.server.com/service/6sxyz/acl/5xUrx/entries' -d '{"entries":[{"op": "create", "ip": "192.168.0.1","subnet": "8"},{"op": "create", "ip": "192.168.0.2", "subnet": "16"}]}'
```

Comment: I get 400 response.

Comment: Added this line: data = json.dumps(payload) and it works now. My json was malformed. I get 200 Response.